# How to add Authentiction to WebApp with Pulumi

Tags: authentication, azure-web-app-service, pulumi

I am trying to add an authentication provider to a Pulumi WebApp but is totaly unclear to me how to achieve that. The class `WebApp` from package `@pulumi/azure-native/web` only offers the property `identity` but no property tho assign e.g. a Microsoft AD. Can anybody provide a hint on how to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some of the  [Pulumi Azure pre-requisites](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/get-started/azure/begin/)  and have the appropriate permissions in your tenant and Azure subscription.

Follow the below steps to add the authentication  to app service webapp with pulumi and deploy:

**Creating the project**:

Start by creating the application, and adding the AzureAD package we’ll need to create the  [Azure AD application registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals).

```
pulumi new azure-csharp `
  --name easyauth-webapp `
  --description "azure ad secured app" `
  --stack dev `
  --config azure-native:location=eastus

dotnet add package Pulumi.AzureAD
```

We next need to update the contents of the `pulumi.dev.yaml` file to contain a few additional config items. Paste the following into the file:

```yaml
config:
  azure-native:location: eastus
  azure-native:subscriptionId: UPDATE_ME
  azure-native:tenantId: UPDATE_ME
  easyauth-webapp:tenantId: UPDATE_ME
  easyauth-webapp:ownerId: UPDATE_ME
  easyauth-webapp:siteName: UPDATE_ME
  easyauth-webapp:appRegistrationName: UPDATE_ME
```

You can set  `siteName`  and  `appRegistrationName`  to whatever you want.

The  `subscriptionId`  and  `tenantId`  should be set to the appropriate target’s for your Azure app service and Azure AD application registration, respectively.

The following commands may be helpful in retrieving these values:

```
# Get your user's id
az ad signed-in-user show --query objectId

# List all subscriptions (and their tenant) that you have access to
az account list
```

**Deploy the website (with no security)**:

We’ll next create the website we want to deploy. We’re going to use the  [run from ZIP package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-run-package)  functionality to deploy the contents of the  `wwwroot`  folder.
Create that folder and add some content to the  `index.htm`  file:

Ex:

```html
<!-- wwwroot/index.htm -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A very secure app</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello EasyAuth with Pulumi!
  </body>
</html>
```

Now we can deploy this file to Azure with Pulumi.
Modify the  `MyStack.cs`  file to contain the below code, which has been adapted from the  [Pulumi Function Stack example](https://github.com/pulumi/examples/blob/master/azure-cs-functions/FunctionsStack.cs):

```cs
// MyStack.cs
using System;
using Pulumi;
using Pulumi.AzureAD;
using Pulumi.AzureAD.Inputs;
using Pulumi.AzureNative.Resources;
using Pulumi.AzureNative.Storage;
using Pulumi.AzureNative.Storage.Inputs;
using Pulumi.AzureNative.Web;
using Pulumi.AzureNative.Web.Inputs;

class MyStack : Stack
{
  public MyStack()
  {
    var config = new Pulumi.Config();
    var tenantId = config.Require("tenantId");
    var ownerId = config.Require("ownerId");
    var siteName = config.Require("siteName");
    var appRegistrationName = config.Require("appRegistrationName");

    var rg = new ResourceGroup($"RG-{siteName}");

    var storageAccount = new StorageAccount("storageaccount", new StorageAccountArgs
    {
      ResourceGroupName = rg.Name,
      Kind = "StorageV2",
      Sku = new SkuArgs
      {
        Name = SkuName.Standard_LRS,
      },
    });

    var appServicePlan = new AppServicePlan("appserviceplan", new AppServicePlanArgs
    {
      ResourceGroupName = rg.Name,
      Kind = "App",
      Sku = new SkuDescriptionArgs
      {
        Tier = "Basic",
        Name = "B1",
      },
    });

    var container = new BlobContainer("zips", new BlobContainerArgs
    {
      AccountName = storageAccount.Name,
      PublicAccess = PublicAccess.None,
      ResourceGroupName = rg.Name,
    });

    var blob = new Blob("appservice-blob", new BlobArgs
    {
      ResourceGroupName = rg.Name,
      AccountName = storageAccount.Name,
      ContainerName = container.Name,
      Type = BlobType.Block,
      Source = new FileArchive("wwwroot"),
    });

    var codeBlobUrl = SignedBlobReadUrl(blob, container, storageAccount, rg);

    var app = new WebApp("app", new WebAppArgs
    {
      Name = siteName,
      ResourceGroupName = rg.Name,
      ServerFarmId = appServicePlan.Id,
      SiteConfig = new SiteConfigArgs
      {
        AppSettings = {
          new NameValuePairArgs{
              Name = "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE",
              Value = codeBlobUrl,
          }
        },
      }
    });

    this.Endpoint = app.DefaultHostName;
  }

  // From https://github.com/pulumi/examples/blob/master/azure-cs-functions/FunctionsStack.cs
  private static Output<string> SignedBlobReadUrl(Blob blob, BlobContainer container, StorageAccount account, ResourceGroup resourceGroup)
  {
    return Output.Tuple<string, string, string, string>(
        blob.Name, container.Name, account.Name, resourceGroup.Name).Apply(t =>
    {
      (string blobName, string containerName, string accountName, string resourceGroupName) = t;

      var blobSAS = ListStorageAccountServiceSAS.InvokeAsync(new ListStorageAccountServiceSASArgs
      {
        AccountName = accountName,
        Protocols = HttpProtocol.Https,
        SharedAccessStartTime = "2021-01-01",
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = "2030-01-01",
        Resource = SignedResource.C,
        ResourceGroupName = resourceGroupName,
        Permissions = Permissions.R,
        CanonicalizedResource = "/blob/" + accountName + "/" + containerName,
        ContentType = "application/json",
        CacheControl = "max-age=5",
        ContentDisposition = "inline",
        ContentEncoding = "deflate",
      });
      return Output.Format($"https://{accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/{containerName}/{blobName}?{blobSAS.Result.ServiceSasToken}");
    });
  }

  [Output] public Output<string> Endpoint { get; set; }
}
```

We can now deploy the site and verify it has worked as intended:

```
pulumi up --stack dev

curl (pulumi stack --stack dev output Endpoint)
```

[[image: HTML output from curl]

**Securing the site**:

To configure Easy Auth we first create an Azure AD application registration.
In this example I’m specifying  `AzureADMyOrg`  which restricts access to the tenant the application registration is deployed in. I’m also adding a  `RedirectUri`  that points at the Easy Auth middleware of the deployed site. A password is needed to use as a client secret (the web application being the client in this case).

Once the application registration is created we can add  [WebAppAuthSettings](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/azure-native/web/webappauthsettings/)  to our site. The example specifies no anonymous access (using  `RedirectToLoginPage`), and connects the site to the application registration using the  `ClientId`  and  `ClientSecret`  (password).

Paste the below code just after the  `this.Endpoint...`  code in the above  `MyStack.cs`:

```cs
// MyStack.cs
// After this.Endpoint = app.DefaultHostName;

var adApp = new Application("ADAppRegistration", new ApplicationArgs
{
  DisplayName = appRegistrationName,
  SignInAudience = "AzureADMyOrg",
  Owners = new[] { ownerId },
  Web = new ApplicationWebArgs
  {
    ImplicitGrant = new ApplicationWebImplicitGrantArgs
    {
      IdTokenIssuanceEnabled = true
    },
    RedirectUris = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string> { $"https://{siteName}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback" }
  }
}
);

var applicationPassword = new ApplicationPassword("appPassword", new ApplicationPasswordArgs
{
  ApplicationObjectId = adApp.Id,
  DisplayName = "Client secret for web app"
});

var allowedAudience = adApp.ApplicationId.Apply(id => $"api://{id}");

var authSettings = new WebAppAuthSettings("authSettings", new WebAppAuthSettingsArgs
{
  ResourceGroupName = rg.Name,
  Name = app.Name,
  Enabled = true,
  UnauthenticatedClientAction = UnauthenticatedClientAction.RedirectToLoginPage,
  DefaultProvider = BuiltInAuthenticationProvider.AzureActiveDirectory,
  ClientId = adApp.ApplicationId,
  ClientSecret = applicationPassword.Value,
  Issuer = $"https://sts.windows.net/{tenantId}/v2.0",
  AllowedAudiences = new[] { allowedAudience },
});
```

We can now update the site, From the command line we can’t get much further than this.
But in a browser we’ll get redirected to complete the login flow and access the site.

```
pulumi up --stack dev

# Redirect to HTTPS
curl (pulumi stack --stack dev output Endpoint)

# Access denied
curl "https://$(pulumi stack --stack dev output Endpoint)"
```

[image: Access denied]

Refer this [Github](https://github.com/taddison/pulumi-csharp-azure-examples/tree/main/easyauth-webapp) link  for pulumi samples.